# Reducing my code

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have the following javascript for a save storage of many divs

```
function savecells() {
    for (var tt = 0; tt < 12; tt++)
        localStorage.setItem(
            'savecellnoinsulation' + (tt + 1), 
            document.getElementById('noinsulation' + (tt + 1)).value
        );
}
```

How do I do this for the following load storage?

```
function loadcells() {

    if (localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation1')) {
        var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation1');
    } else {
        var answer = ' ';
    }
    document.getElementById('noinsulation1').value = answer;

    if (localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation2')) {
        var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation2');
    } else {
        var answer = ' ';
    }
    document.getElementById('noinsulation2').value = answer;

    if (localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation3')) {
        var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation3');
    } else {
        var answer = ' ';
    }
    document.getElementById('noinsulation3').value = answer;

    if (localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation4')) {
        var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation4');
    } else {
        var answer = ' ';
    }
    document.getElementById('noinsulation4').value = answer;

    if (localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation5')) {
        var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation5');
    } else {
        var answer = ' ';
    }
    document.getElementById('noinsulation5').value = answer;

    if (localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation6')) {
        var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation6');
    } else {
        var answer = ' ';
    }
    document.getElementById('noinsulation6').value = answer;

    if (localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation7')) {
        var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation7');
    } else {
        var answer = ' ';
    }
    document.getElementById('noinsulation7').value = answer;

    if (localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation8')) {
        var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation8');
    } else {
        var answer = ' ';
    }
    document.getElementById('noinsulation8').value = answer;

    if (localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation9')) {
        var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation9');
    } else {
        var answer = ' ';
    }
    document.getElementById('noinsulation9').value = answer;

    if (localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation10')) {
        var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation10');
    } else {
        var answer = ' ';
    }
    document.getElementById('noinsulation10').value = answer;

    if (localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation11')) {
        var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation11');
    } else {
        var answer = ' ';
    }
    document.getElementById('noinsulation11').value = answer;

    if (localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation12')) {
        var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation12');
    } else {
        var answer = ' ';
    }
    document.getElementById('noinsulation12').value = answer;
}
```

I did try a similar method but it failed to work. Is this even possible? Not sure what else to try!

Thanks

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: Might be worth asking your question at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that reverses the `savecells()` function. If the page layout is the same as the page where you saved them, it will just take all the values and put them back where they came from.

```
function retreiveCells() {
    for (var tt = 0; tt < 12; tt++){
        document.getElementById('noinsulation' + (tt + 1)).value = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation' + (tt + 1)) || '' ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation4')) {
    var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulation4');
} 
else {
    var answer = ' ';
}
```

by: `var answer = localStorage.getItem('savecellnoinsulationX') || '';`

Ands use an array containing all the names of the itmes, or just the end of it, and you can generate the string to check in a `for loop`

So basically the following should work:

```
for (var i=1; i<=12; i++) { 
    var itemStr = "noinsulation" + i;
    var saveItemStr = "savecell" + item;
    var answer = localStorage.getItem(saveItemStr) || '';
    document.getElementById(itemStr).value = answer;
}
```